# Array not being passed to EJS

Tags: node.js, ejs

I am working on a nodejs project with MongoDB for database storage and EJS for templating.

I've encountered a problem where an array of objects is not being correctly passed to EJS. The code works as expected in *forums.js* (and outputs as expected from console.log) but does not work correctly in *forums.ejs*. Upon loading the project, I am given an error: "Can not read property forEach of undefined".

Can anyone help me out here? Thank you!

**forums.js**

```
var allCategories = await dbo.getForumCategories();
    
allCategories.forEach(async function(category) {    
    category.forumArray = await dbo.getForums({categoryId: new ObjectID(category._id)}); 
    console.log(category.forumArray); //works fine, displays as intended
});
    
res.render('forums.ejs', { categories: allCategories,  user: req.user });
```

**forums.ejs**

```
<% categories.forEach(function(category) { %>
//this part works
//some code

<% category.forumArray.forEach(function(forum) { %>
//this is not working
//Can not read property forEach of undefined

<% }); %>
<% }); %>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because your `render` function is being called before your `forEach` has finished running.

See the below example:

```js
const foo = [1, 2, 3];

foo.forEach(async function(bar) {
    bar = await mockCall() + bar;
})

console.log(foo) //> [ 1, 2, 3 ]
console.log("Are methods here running?") //> Logs correctly and demonstrates any function here would run before the `foo.forEach` is done running.

function mockCall() {
    return new Promise((res, rej) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            res('From the promise: ');
        }, 500)
    })
}
```

Comment: Thanks. How can I fix this within my example?

Answer (score 0):

In your res.render you pass categories as allCategories but I cant see where category from the ejs file is defined.

Comment: sorry my fault - found it :)

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed my code by replacing the for each loop with a for loop as follows:

```
for (const category of allCategories) {
    category.forumArray = await dbo.getForums({categoryId: new ObjectID(category._id)});
}
```